# Вставка нескольких строк в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма из 4 наименований, как вставить строки в базу одним запросом через php?

```
<input type="text" name="name1">
<input type="text" name="name2">
<input type="text" name="name3">
<input type="text" name="name4">

$name = $_POST['name']);

INSERT INTO table(name)VALUES('$name'))
```

Comment: http://staff.washington.edu/weller/php/forms.php

Comment: Например воспользоваться функцией `join($_POST);` если не важно как нужно вставлять, будет все слито. Или можно передавать разделитель первым аргументом `join(' ',$_POST);` - будет через пробел. Если нужно вставлять в разные колонки, то воспользоваться циклом `foreach` - если название `input` = `названию колонок`.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, но если я вас правильно понял, то: `INSERT INTO 'TABLE' ('field_1','field_2','field_3','field_4') VALUES ('text_1','text_2','text_3','text_4')`, где `field_№` - название полей в которых записать, а `text_№` - ваши данные. Если не юзаете фреймворки, то используйте `PDO` (гуглится)

Comment: правильно поняли, только у меня может быть вместо 4-x другое количество строк, до 9, поэтому этот вариант отпадает

Comment: так через запятую добавьте еще 5 -.-

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ('value1-1', 'value1-2'), ('value2-1', 'value2-2'), ('value3-1', 'value3-2');
```

Такой запрос добавит в таблицу 3 строки

Comment: И у меня звязан с таким запросом другой вопрос.

Допустим у меня с колонке `column2 стоит индекс UNIQUE
Как при выполнении такого такого запроса добавить две строки из примера, если третья стока вызывает ошибку "Duplicate entry ... for key ..."

Comment: Если у вас другой вопрос, то его надо погуглить. Ответ находится очень быстро.

Comment: Да. Уже нашел INSERT IGNORE INTO table…